# Java CompletableFuture thenCompose with several async tasks

Tags: java, concurrency, completable-future

I have a process made by 2 async steps. The second steps run based on the result of the first step. The process is launched in a loop. The challenge is that the second step is made by several async tasks taking the output of one first step iteration. As soon as a first step is finished, I would like to launch the n seconds steps using this first step result. I made this piece of code using `CompletableFuture` and `thenCompose`.

It works but I find it quite complex and I am wondering if it is the proper way to do it. I am especially wondering if the management of the second level sub-tasks and the use of `CompletableFuture.allOf` to make it like it is a single `CompletableFuture` is the proper way of doing.

```
public void test() {
    // Gather CompletableFutures to wait for them at the end
    List<CompletableFuture> futures = new ArrayList<>();

    // First steps
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int finalI = i;
        CompletableFuture<Void> fut = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            logger.debug("Start step 1 - " + finalI);
            simulateLongProcessing();// just waits for 1 s
            logger.debug("End step 1 - " + finalI);
            return "step1 output - " + finalI;
        }).thenCompose(s -> {
            List<CompletableFuture> subFutures = new ArrayList<>();
            // Second step : Launch several sub-tasks based on the result of the first step
            for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
                final int finalJ = j;
                CompletableFuture<String> f = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                    logger.debug("Start - step 2 : " + s + " | " + finalJ);
                    simulateLongProcessing();
                    logger.debug("End - step 2 : " + s + " | " + finalJ);
                    return "step2 output - " + s + " | " + finalJ;
                });
                subFutures.add(f);
            }
            return CompletableFuture.allOf(subFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));
        });
        futures.add(fut);
    }

    // Wait for the completion
    for (CompletableFuture future : futures) {
        future.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think what makes this look complex is the loops creating the many futures. If you refactor the method so that the nested loop or the `thenCompose` lambda goes to a separate method, it will look simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Don’t perform a `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` within a function passed to `thenCompose` when you can chain the same depend function with a straight-forward `thenApplyAsync`.

Chaining the dependent functions via `thenApplyAsync` allows you to get the `CompletableFuture` instances representing these steps before the first steps completed, so you can collect them all into your `List` to wait for their completion at the end and don’t need to create compound futures via `CompletableFuture.allOf`.

```
public void test() {
    // Gather CompletableFutures to wait for them at the end
    List<CompletableFuture<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int finalI = i;
        CompletableFuture<String> step1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            logger.debug("Start step 1 - " + finalI);
            simulateLongProcessing();// just waits for 1 s
            logger.debug("End step 1 - " + finalI);
            return "step1 output - " + finalI;
        });
        // Second step : Chain several sub-tasks based on the result of the first step
        for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
            final int finalJ = j;
            futures.add(step1.thenApplyAsync(s -> {
                logger.debug("Start - step 2 : " + s + " | " + finalJ);
                simulateLongProcessing();
                logger.debug("End - step 2 : " + s + " | " + finalJ);
                return "step2 output - " + s + " | " + finalJ;
            }));
        }
    }

    // Wait for the completion
    for (CompletableFuture<?> future : futures) {
        future.join();
    }
}
```